# Can I fetch the data provided for my Server in Discord's "Server Insights" using a REST API?

Tags: rest, discord

I'd like to be able to ping my discord server and get a response containing the member count(at least).

Ideally I could do this using Discord's API, with an endpoint like `https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/1234567890/member_count`

Does anyone have any insights into the best way to get this data?

Thanks!

Comment: If that's a real endpoint, what problems are you running into trying to call it?